telegram api does not send reply_to_message in message
The user used a bot and when he replied to the message, reply_to_message always came. Recently, reply_to_message has not been received from this user when he responds. What could be the reason? The bot settings have not changed. The message type is private.
That the user responds there are screenshots, all updates are logged in the same way.
